# how to load back after return false?

Tags: php

After executing this codes the page wont load

```
if($rr["PatientId"]!=""){
      echo"<script>alert('The patient you register is already have account')</script>";
      return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the closing `}` in the original code? However, if you `return` the fun is over.

Comment: try `var_dump($rr["PatientId"])` to check whats in it ? also you'r missing `}`

Comment: yes i have } in my original codes

Comment: Is this statement contained within a function?

Comment: nope it not contained a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you  `return` ( no matter if true or false ) the code doesn't get executed any further. 2 things:

1.Try it like this:

```
if($rr["PatientId"]!=""){
      echo"<script>
                alert('The patient you register is already have account')     
           </script>";
} else {
 register_user($register_data); 
 echo" <script> alert('Successful Adding Patient') </script>"; 
}
```

2.Even if you would want to return if you don't show the alert, you wouldn't need the else statement. This statement will never be reached if the condition for your if statement evaluates to true, so you don't need to use `else {}` after an `if` with return if it's the only other choice you give.

[image]

Comment: my problem is i have also alertbox after that so if the patient register already the alert box successful adding also showing

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your what you mean

Comment: after that query ihave this register_user($register_data);
 
 
 echo" <script> alert('Successful Adding Patient')  </script>";

Comment: I made an edit, do you mean like this? @MaricarManlulu